# for - loop for group of elements in vector that references other vector

Tags: c++, vector, find, pow, accumulate

I am trying to find out why this piece of code returns -1. The fault lies within this piece of code, and I guess I am handling the iterators wrongly here. What I am trying to do is calculate a geometric mean. You can fault me for several things here I guess but first and foremost I am trying to understand the logic.

```
double indicators::GeoMean(input* Close1, input* Date1, int CurrDate, int StartDate) {

double temp1;
p1 = find(Date1->YearMonthDay.begin(),Date1->YearMonthDay.end(),StartDate); // <std::vector<int>::const_iterator>
auto positA = std::distance(Date1->YearMonthDay.begin(), p1);
cout << positA << endl;
p2 = find(Date1->YearMonthDay.begin(),Date1->YearMonthDay.end(),CurrDate);
auto positB = std::distance(Date1->YearMonthDay.begin(), p2);
cout << positB << endl;
       // Start with the number 1. Add or subract to that number according to gain or loss. 
    for ( int i = positA; i > positB; i--) {
        temp1 = 1.0 + ((Close1->Close[i-1] - Close1->Close[i]) / Close1->Close[i]);
        daily.push_back(temp1);
        }
        double days = 1.0/daily.size();         
        double temp2 = std::accumulate(daily.begin(), daily.end(), 0.0, std::multiplies<double>());
        double GM = (pow(temp2, days) ) -1.0; 
        cout << "GM is " << GM << endl;
    // The geometric mean will always be equal to or less than the arithmetic mean.
return GM;
```

}
It seems as though the decimals are being cut off here:

```
double temp2 = std::accumulate(daily.begin(), daily.end(), 0.0, std::multiplies<double>());
```

I have a vague idea that int value is taking precedence over double here somewhere, but I cannot understand where. In addition to that my handling of the for- loop here leaves something to be desired. The referenced class objects here have been well - used in other functions, so the problem lies within this code. The integer arguments for the function are dates as pure integers, used in an interface, and they class object vectors all have the same indexes for reference of data. 
The find functions and distance give me the exact indexes of the dates I search the vector for, so that I can go back and use those indexes on the Close- price vector.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you use multiplication and start with 0.0 you will just multiply everything by 0 and never get anywhere. Try using 1.0 as a start value.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem!